# Alert Dialog with custom layout failing

Tags: android

So this is related to a question I asked earlier. I am trying to display an alert using a specified layout. My layout is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/layout_root"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:padding="10dp">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:textColor="#FFF" />   
</LinearLayout>
```

And the code to call and show the alert dialog is:

```
    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    // use a custom View defined in xml
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.sell_dialog,      (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            // do whatever you want with the input
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

    alertDialog.show();
```

When I run it I get an error saying:

Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
android.view.WindowManager$NadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

I've looked through the android development site and can't figure it out. I think I'm just missing something obvious but the fix isn't jumping out at me. How can I get this alert dialog to display?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not use `getApplicationContext()`. That method is only available on a `Context` (e.g., `Activity`) -- use that `Context` for your `AlertDialog.Builder`.

[Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/Constants/) from one of my books that, among other things, shows an `AlertDialog` based off of a custom `View`.

Comment: I am interested in the example of the Alert Dialog that uses a custom view, however your link has no such example.

Comment: @Nemi: Whoops, you're right. Sorry about that. Try this one: http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-colormixer

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to create an AlertDialog with a custom view AND use the setMessage() string, but I find that if the message string is long enough to invoke the scrollbars in the internal listView that the layout gets screwed up. I was hoping your example would shed some insight, but it looks like I may have to write a complete custom dialog.

Comment: Thanks, I used your example from ConstantsBrowser.java and it works great. I don't know why they don't update the Android Dialogs Information page where the original poster got his example. I had the exact same problem with it trying to do the custom layout Alert Dialog Builder inside a ExpandableListActivity class. Cheers!